# Importing shapefile data using GeoDataFrame

Tags: geopandas

I am using GeoDataFrame for the data importing. But have the following problems. Actually this function works well for some shapefiles, but does not work so well for some specific shapefiles and I am wondering why

```
data = GeoDataFrame.from_file('bayarea_general.shp')



fiona/ogrext.pyx in fiona.ogrext.Iterator.__next__ (fiona/ogrext.c:17244)()

fiona/ogrext.pyx in fiona.ogrext.FeatureBuilder.build (fiona/ogrext.c:3254)()

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Are you able to share the shapefile (or a reproducing sample of it)?

Comment: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/227  similar to this~

Comment: It does not work for most of the shapefiles as for me...

Comment: That indeed seems a similar problem. Do you have gdal 2 installed (as pointed out in the issue solved it by downgrading gdal)

Comment: You need to post the "some specific shapefiles" in question.